# How to make Laravel controller store file upload with a relationship

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, foreign-keys

I am trying to store an uploaded file with a relationship to an Employee model. I am unable to retrieve the employee id after uploading the file to save it to the DB table as a foreign key. 
Routes:

```
Route::resource('employees', 'EmployeesController');
Route::post('documents', 'DocumentsController@createdocument')
```

So I am on a URL that says `http://localhost/public/employees/8` when I hit upload it redirects to `http://localhost/public/documents` and the file does upload but shows error when writing to DB.

Here is my code. How can I do it?

```
public function createdocument(Request $request, Employee $id)
{
    $file = $request->file('file');
    $allowedFileTypes = config('app.allowedFileTypes');
    $maxFileSize = config('app.maxFileSize');
    $rules = [
        'file' => 'required|mimes:'.$allowedFileTypes.'|max:'.$maxFileSize
    ];
    $this->validate($request, $rules);


    $time = time();  // Generates a random string of 20 characters
    $filename = ($time.'_'.($file->getClientOriginalName())); // Prepend the filename with 
     $destinationPath = config('app.fileDestinationPath').'/'.$filename;
        $uploaded = Storage::put($destinationPath, file_get_contents($file->getRealPath()));

        if($uploaded){      
        $employee = Employee::find($id);            
        $empdoc = new EmpDocuments();
        $empdoc->name = $filename;
        $empdoc->employee_id = $employee->id;       
        $empdoc->save();

        }    
        return redirect('employees');
}
```

These are my models.

Employee.php

```
public function EmpDocuments()
    {
    return $this->hasMany('App\EmpDocuments');
    }

    public function createdocument(){
   return $this->EmpDocuments()->create([
          'name' => $filename,
          'employee_id' => $id,
          ]);
    }
```

EmpDocuments.php

```
public function Employee()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Employee');
    }
```

With the above models and controller I am now getting error

> General error: 1364 Field 'employee_id' doesn't have a default value (SQL: insert into empdocuments.

How do I capture the employee_id?

Managed to fix it, in case someone has similar problem. Ensure you pass the id with the route action for it to be capture in the next request. 
Here is the final controller.

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{    


    $file = $request->file('file');
    $allowedFileTypes = config('app.allowedFileTypes');
    $maxFileSize = config('app.maxFileSize');
    $rules = [
        'file' => 'required|mimes:'.$allowedFileTypes.'|max:'.$maxFileSize
    ];
    $this->validate($request, $rules);


    $time = time();  // Generates a random string of 20 characters
    $filename = ($time.'_'.($file->getClientOriginalName())); // Prepend the filename with 
     $destinationPath = config('app.fileDestinationPath').'/'.$filename;
        $uploaded = Storage::put($destinationPath, file_get_contents($file->getRealPath()));



        if($uploaded){

        $employee = Employee::find($id);
        $empdoc = new EmpDocuments();
        $empdoc->name = $filename; 
        $employee->empdocuments()->save($empdoc);
        return redirect('employees/' . $id . '#documents')->with('message','Document has been uploaded');

        }
}
```

Comment: In your controller's `createdocument` method, try to `dd($id)` and see what it contains, I guess you would be getting the `Employee` instance/model object and not just an id.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a relationship between Employee and EmpDocuments ??
If I am understanding well EmpDocuments belongsTO Employees right??

I'm trying to help but I need to understand, one employee can have many documents right?? but each document belongs to just one employee right??

If is like that you should make a relationship in your employee model,

```
` public function employeeDocuments(){
      return $this->hasMany(EmpDocuments::class);
    }`
```

Then in the same model

```
`public function createEmployeeDocuments(){
   return $this->employeeDocuments()->create([
          'your_db_fields' =>your file,
          'your_db_fields' => your other some data, 
          ]);
  }`
```

The id will be inserted automatically
I hope I helped you!!
https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships

Are your fillable empty???
To use the Eloquent create method you need to set you fillable array to mass assignment. Try this, if is still not working tell me and I will try to do my best.

`protected $fillable = [ 'employee_id', 'Your_db_field', 'Your_db_field', 'per_page', 'Your_db_field', 'Your_db_field' ];`

Comment: Mendez I have updated models but still no luck. Your interpretation is correct Employee can have many documents, a document belongs to 1 employee.

Comment: $employee = Employee::find($id);

When I dd($employee); on this line it returns null. So what code is required to get the employee object http://localhost/public/employees/8

Comment: @EdenWebStudio Please Could you votein my answer if the answer was helfull for you? Thank you so much